# Method \UserController::sendError does not exist while trying to validate inputs laravel+vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, validation

so i'm working on a project with vuejs front and laravel back 
i want ot make sure that the user put some validated data before to try to add it into the database 
this is the createuser method in userController

```
public function createUser(Request $request){
          $input = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email'=>'email|required|unique',
            'reg_num'=>'required',
            'post_id'=>'required'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());

        }

        $user = new User;
        $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
        $user->id_card = $request->id_card;
        $user->reg_num = $request->reg_num;
        $user->phone_num = $request->phone_num;
        $user->landline = $request->landline;
        $user->address = $request->address;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->birth_date = $request->birth_date;
        $user->rec_date = $request->rec_date;
        $user->end_service_date = $request->end_service_date;
        $user->education_lvl = $request->education_lvl;
        $user->contract_type = $request->contract_type;
        $user->cv = '';
        $user->motivation_letter = '';
        $user->center_interest = $request->center_interest;
        $user->nb_hour = $request->nb_hour;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->post_id = $request->post_id;
        $user->nb_holidays = 24;
        $user->banned =0;
        $user->admin = 0;
        $user->photo_url = '';
        $user->gender = $request->gender;



        $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "User record created"
        ], 201);
    }
```

when i try to send the request with empty inputs i got this error 
**Request failed with status code 500** 
instead i want to get the message that the inputs are empty ..
**can someone help me please** 
this is how i catch the error in the front

```
.catch((error) =>(this.errors.push(error.response.data)))
```

when i do that i got the error above but when i do this

```
.catch((error) =>(this.errors.push(error)))
```

i got this .. [image: the error on psotman]

Comment: Does `sendError` exist on a controller. To my knowledge it does not.

Comment: i thought while i'm using the Validator i need to use it .. should i change it , but with wht?

Answer (score 0):

So this is how to create a standard request, you 'can' create them in the controller, but a more standard was of doing it is by making a FormRequest see documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests

You can create form requests using this command `php artisan make:request StoreUserRequest`

This way you can set the request in the params of the controller method as `StoreUserRequest $request`.

Then inside this Request you can set the rules much like you did here, but it will deal with the data failing automatically and it will return `422` and will return the errors, it will be quite deep in to the object that it returns, but it is there.

However if you do want to do validation in the controller you can access the `->errors()` on the Validator.

Note:
Just a couple small things, I would take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts, which will show you an easier way of creating records.

And since all your fields look like they match the database, you can look at the `$request->validated()` method which will return all fields validated by the validator. This will be all fields that pass validation that are in the rules array.

Or you can use `$request->only()` or `$request->except()` and then array merge the password in and the fields you need to cast as a bool (banned and admin)

Comment: this could help me .. but i need to know something . here i have an error about the sendError method .. can i just replace it with something that can work out for me

Comment: You cannot return errors like this, without doing the request but you can get the errors and add them to the response like I said above,

"However if you do want to do validation in the controller you can access the ->errors() on the Validator."